# Theorem 20 Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra book Section 3.6

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

What I don't understand here is why is $h(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha$ in $N_{k}$.
Is there a typo?

In case there is not, could someone please detail that last step please?

Comment: By construction, the restriction of $h$ to $N_k$ is $g' - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}f_i'$ - which is $0$, by construction.

Comment: Is it that simple? huh?(scratching my head...)

Comment: Does the author use the induction ipothesis: $g=\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}c_{i}f_{i}$ ? If not what is the induction ipothesis?

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that for all vector spaces $V$, and all systems $(\mu,\{\lambda_i : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant r\})$ of linear functionals on $V$, with $r < k$, and $\mathcal{N}(\mu) \supset \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r \mathcal{N}(\lambda_i)$, you can write $\mu$ as a linear combination of the $\lambda_i$. The induction hypothesis is applied to the space $V = N_k$, and the system $(g', \{ f_i' : 1 \leqslant i < k\})$.

Comment: I don't understand the notation you use, could you please use a simpler notation? Or explain for example, what do you mean by systems of linear functionals, or what do you mean by the big fancy character that looks like N?

Comment: The $\mathcal{N}(f)$ denotes the null space, or kernel, of $f$. By system, I mean the kind of data the theorem is concerned with. You have a finite set of linear functionals (the $f_i$ resp $\lambda_i$), and another linear functional ($g$ or $\mu$) that vanishes on the intersection of the null spaces of the $f_i$ ($\lambda_i$).

Comment: Do you mean "vanishes off" or "vanishes of"?

Comment: I meant "vanishes **on**". Fixed now.

Comment: I think I understand. In the case it's not too much to ask from you, what's the point of the sentence : "Furthermore, if $\alpha$ is a vector in $N_{k}$ and $f'_{i}=0$, $i=1, ..., k-1$, then $\alpha$ is in the intersection of the $N_{i}$'s (i from 1 to k-1) and so $g'(\alpha)=0$."?

Comment: It says that the system of the restrictions of $g$ and the $f_i$ to $N_k$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem. Without restricting to $N_k$, we don't know that $g$ vanishes on $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} N_i$ - in general, it doesn't. But $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} N_i' = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k N_i$, so the restriction of $g$ to $N_k$ vanishes on that.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*Answered by  [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486872/theorem-20-hoffman-kunze-linear-algebra-book-section-3-6#comment1047883_486872) in a comment*

> By construction, the restriction of $h$ to $N_k$ is $g' - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}f_i'$ - which is $0$, by construction.

*Additional details*

The induction hypothesis is that for all vector spaces $V$, and all systems $(\mu,\{\lambda_i : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant r\})$ of linear functionals on $V$, with $r < k$, and $\mathcal{N}(\mu) \supset \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r \mathcal{N}(\lambda_i)$, you can write $\mu$ as a linear combination of the $\lambda_i$. The induction hypothesis is applied to the space $V = N_k$, and the system $(g', \{ f_i' : 1 \leqslant i < k\})$.

Here $\mathcal{N}(f)$ denotes the null space, or kernel, of $f$. By system, I mean the kind of data the theorem is concerned with. You have a finite set of linear functionals (the $f_i$ resp $\lambda_i$), and another linear functional ($g$ or $\mu$) that vanishes on the intersection of the null spaces of the $f_i$ ($\lambda_i$).

Comment: Well, could you collect the answer in the comments in *this* answer?

Comment: @Care Bear Thank you.